# PDFBox Rendering Jpeg2000 and JBIG2

Tags: java, pdf, tomcat, pdfbox, jbig2

I want to convert each pdf page into an image (like a screen shot), and then upload that image to a storage service.

```
  private void getImageBytes(PDDocument document, int pageIndex, int dpi, ConcurrentHashMap<String, byte[]> imgsToUpload, String imgKey) throws IOException {


    PDFRenderer pdfRenderer = new PDFRenderer(document);
    BufferedImage bim = pdfRenderer.renderImageWithDPI(pageIndex, dpi, ImageType.RGB);
    final ByteArrayOutputStream os = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    ImageIO.write(bim, "png", os); // import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
    os.flush();
    os.close();
    imgsToUpload.put(imgKey, os.toByteArray());
  }
```

I did import `jbig2-imageio` by adding this snippet to pom.xml

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.pdfbox</groupId>
            <artifactId>pdfbox</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.19</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.pdfbox/jbig2-imageio -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.pdfbox</groupId>
            <artifactId>jbig2-imageio</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.3</version>
        </dependency>
```

but still the generated images are blank. and this error is logged : `Cannot read JPEG2000 image: Java Advanced Imaging (JAI) Image I/O Tools are not installed`

So, what did i miss ? , i assumed that adding the dependency would resolve that error.

should i use pdfbox-tools.imageIo instead of java.imageio

PS: I am New to Java, so i it might be a configuration thing ??

Comment: Is this a straight forward stand alone program? Or something in tomcat?

Comment: @TilmanHausherr, it is a spring boot application running tomcat as a server., basically what this endpoint does is , extract all form fields from the pdf, and also each page as an image.

Comment: I remember reading this about tomcat... and I found that it was discussed before, but no solution: https://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/pdfbox-users/201808.mbox/browser  I wonder whether it works if you put that jar file in the tomcat directory where the tomcat jar files are?

Comment: I just restarted my PC, and it worked, I really don't know what happened or what was wrong.

@TilmanHausherr, but the images have black stains, i found one of your answers that is a bug with JAI, and it was solved but not released.

Comment: Yeah, you need to do your own build with the modifications mentioned. IIRC the main modification is in the repository.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add these dependencies in your pom file in order to solve the issue.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.github.jai-imageio</groupId>
    <artifactId>jai-imageio-core</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.github.jai-imageio</groupId>
    <artifactId>jai-imageio-jpeg2000</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.0</version>
</dependency>
```

https://pdfbox.apache.org/2.0/dependencies.html#optional-components

Comment: jai-imageio-jpeg2000 is at 1.4.0 and that one contains the "inkblot" bugfix